# 'swift name'属性はこの宣言に適用できません〜の解決法

Tags: swift, realm

本に書いてあった下記のコードを実行するとRealmのRLMConstants.hというファイルに「'swift_name' attribute cannot be applied to this declaration」というエラーが出ます。ネットで探してもそれらしいのは見つかりません。解決方法を御教示いただけますでしょうか。
参考にしている本は、「[ほんきで学ぶSwift+iOSアプリ開発入門](https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%81%BB%E3%82%93%E3%81%8D%E3%81%A7%E5%AD%A6%E3%81%B6Swift-iOS%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E9%96%8B%E7%99%BA%E5%85%A5%E9%96%80-Swift2-Xcode7-iOS9%E5%AF%BE%E5%BF%9C/dp/4798142352)(ISBN-10:4798142352)」です。Realmは最新版です。xcodeは７.１です。

① ViewController.swiftのコード

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    // デフォルトの Realm インスタンスを取得する
    let realm = try! Realm()

    // DB 内の日記データが格納されるリスト(日付新しいもの順でソート：降順)。以降内容をアップデートするとリスト内は自動的に更新される。
    let dataArray = try! Realm().objects(Diary).sorted("date", ascending: false)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // 入力画面から戻ってきた時に TableView を更新させる
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    // segue で画面遷移するに呼ばれる
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){
        let inputViewController:InputViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! InputViewController

        if segue.identifier == "cellSegue" {
            let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
            inputViewController.diary = dataArray[indexPath!.row]
        } else {
            let diary = Diary()
            diary.title = "タイトル"
            diary.body = "本文"
            if dataArray.count != 0 {
                diary.id = dataArray.max("id")! + 1
            }

            inputViewController.diary = diary
        }
    }

    // MARK: UITableViewDataSource プロトコルのメソッド
    // TableView の各セクションのセルの数を返す
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataArray.count
    }

    // 各セルの内容を返す
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // 再利用可能な cell を得る
        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        // Cellに値を設定する.
        let object = dataArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = object.title
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = object.date.description
        return cell
    }

    // MARK: UITableViewDataSource プロトコルのメソッド
    // Delete ボタンが押された時の処理を行う
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
            try! realm.write {
                self.realm.delete(self.dataArray[indexPath.row])
                tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            }
        }
    }

    // セルが削除が可能なことを伝える
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)-> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete;
    }

    // 各セルを選択した時に実行される
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("cellSegue",sender: nil)
    }
}
```

②InputViewController.swiftのコード

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class InputViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var titleTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var bodyTextView: UITextView!

    let realm = try! Realm()
    var diary: Diary!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // NavigationBar の戻るボタンを消す
        self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated:false);

        titleTextField.text = diary.title
        bodyTextView.text = diary.body

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func save(sender: UIButton) {
        try! realm.write {
            self.diary.title = self.titleTextField.text!
            self.diary.body = self.bodyTextView.text
            self.diary.date = NSDate()
            self.realm.add(self.diary, update: true)
        }

        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

③Diary.swiftのコード

```
import RealmSwift
class Diary: Object {
    dynamic var id = 0

    // タイトル
    dynamic var title = ""

    // 本文
    dynamic var body = ""

    /// 最終更新日時
    dynamic var date = NSDate()

    /**
     id をプライマリーキーとして設定
     */
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

Comment: Swift 2のコードだと思いますので参考にしている本がかなり古いと思われます。なんという本でしょうか？また、使用しているRealmのバージョンはわかりますか？

Comment: fukuta さんによる、編集提案が来ていますが、 fukuta さんと satei290 さんは同一人物でいらっしゃいますでしょうか？その場合は、[こちら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) から、アカウントのマージ申請を行っていただけますでしょうか。というのも、質問作成者本人と、それ以外では、自身の質問に対して行える編集などの行動に制限がかかってしまいますので。。

Comment: 編集提案を承認しました。これでOKでしょうか。お手数をおかけしました。

Comment: 最新版ということはRealmは2.10.2でしょうか。いずれにしてもRealmがSwift 2とXcode 7をサポートしていたのはバージョン2.3.0までですので、最新版を使うならXcodeを8以上に上げて、Swiftも3以上を使う必要があります。なんの目的でSwiftを勉強されているかによりますが、SwiftやiOSアプリ開発が目的なら、残念ながらその本は古すぎて、初心者の方がこれから学ぶという用途には適していないので、別の最近出版された本を使って勉強されることをオススメします。Realmの使い方が知りたいのであれば、「軽量・高速モバイルデータベースRealm入門」という書籍がオススメです。

Comment: オススメの本のTwitterのAPIを使うものより、古い本の日記アプリを作るものの方が、自分がSwiftで作りたいものに近く且つ判り易そうだったものですから先に手を着けていました。何とかRealmSwiftを使えるようになりたいのでxcodeのバージョンを上げて試したり、オススメの本も早速読んで試してみます。御教示に感謝します。

Comment: @satei290 今からSwiftの本を買うのであれば、もう少し待ってSwift4にした方がハッピーな気もしなくもないです。ただしネット上のSwift4の資料はまだ少なめなのでSwift3から入るかは判断次第です。

Comment: 2と3はまったく別物ですが、Swift 3とSwift 4はソースコードレベルの非互換は本当に少ないので、Swift 3で学ぶことはそれほど問題ではありません。

Comment: swift4の本が出てからRealmのことが書いてあるものを探してみたいと思います。その前に少し古い本で試していようと思います。いろいろ御教示をいただき感謝します。